# Invert string in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do a simple string inversion in Rust, but I can't seem to figure out what functions to use in order to do this.

Say I have a string: `____x_xx__x`

inverting this string will become: `xxxx_x__xx_`

I tried:

```
//res is the string I want to invert
for mut c in res.as_slice().chars() {
  c =
    match c {
      'x' => '_',
       _  => 'x'
    };
};
```

but this warns me that the value `c` is never read, so I guess the `c` I am using is not actually a reference to the character in the slice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn main() {
    let mut res = String::from_str("____x_xx__x").into_ascii();

    for c in res.mut_iter() {
        *c = match c.to_char() {
            'x' => '_',
             _  => 'x'
        }.to_ascii();
    };

    println!("{}", res.into_string());
}
```

[play.rust-lang.org](http://is.gd/JFYUf9)

Comment: This should come with the caveat that the string must be entirely ASCII (that is, it's not enough for just the character(s) being inverted to be ASCII).

Comment: my rust is telling me that `into_string()` does not exist for `Vec<std::ascii::Ascii>`

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I suspect you must update your rust, as it changes very frequently. I dunno which version is on play.rust-lang.org, but it works there.

Answer (score 3):

`.chars()` yields `char` instances which are not references in any way.

To be able to modify such a thing in place, you would need to have a mutable slice.

A `String` is UTF-8 encoded; if you wish to do it in place, any character replacement *must* be for a character with the same number of bytes; the simplest case for that is ASCII. (And with your examples of `x` and `_`, it *must* be ASCII.)

The way to implement this in place would be [`as_mut_bytes()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_mut_bytes) and its [`mut_iter()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/primitive.slice.html#method.mut_iter):

```
let bytes = unsafe { res.as_mut_slice() };
for c in bytes.mut_iter() {
    *c = match *c {
        'x' => '_',
        _ if c.len_utf8_bytes() > 1 => fail!("you tried to make me make bad UTF-8"),
        _ => 'x',
    }
}
```

(I inserted the [`len_utf8_bytes()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/trait.Char.html#tymethod.len_utf8_bytes) branch to guarantee the UTF-8 invariant. It may be omitted—though putting it as a `debug_assert!` is still probably a good idea—if you *know* you’re only dealing with ASCII.)

---

Alternatively, you could create a new string out of it. This would cope with non-ASCII strings.

```
res.chars().map(|c| if c == 'x' { '_' } else { 'x' }).collect::<String>()
```

Using codepoints as the boundaries isn’t very precise either, so let’s work with [grapheme clusters](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.UnicodeStrSlice.html#tymethod.graphemes) for this case instead.

```
res.graphemes(true).map(|c| if c == "x" { '_' } else { 'x' }).collect::<String>()
```

Comment: The safe and efficient way to map in-place for guaranteed ASCII input is via [`.into_ascii()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/ascii/trait.OwnedAsciiCast.html#method.into_ascii) + `.mut_iter()` + [`into_string()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/to_str/trait.IntoStr.html#tymethod.into_string). (This portion of the libraries definitely needs some work...)

Comment: do I need to include anything? rust says that `as_mut_slice()` is not a part of `String` and I don't see anything similar on strings documentation

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

http://is.gd/uXdoRf

```
fn new_str(s: &String) -> String {
    let mut s2 = String::new();
    for i in range(0,s.len()) {
        s2 = s2.append(if s.as_slice().char_at(i) == '_' { "x" } else { "_" });
    }
    s2
}

fn in_place(s: &mut String) {
    for _i in range(0,s.len()) {
        let c = s.shift_char();
        match c {
            Some(x) => s.grow(1,if x == '_' { 'x' } else { '_' }),
            None => return
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from_str("___xxx__x_");
    let s2 = new_str(&s);
    println!("{}",s);
    println!("{}",s2);
    let mut s3 = String::from_str("___xxx__x_");
    in_place(&mut s3);
    println!("{}",s3);
}
```

Output:

```
___xxx__x_
xxx___xx_x
xxx___xx_x
```

Annoyingly enough the in place version is O(n^2) since "shift_char" is O(n). I'm not sure how to alter a single character directly though.

Comment: The first function will blow up in your face if the UTF-8 string contains any codepoints beyond 127. The index for char_at is a byte offset and if you use an offest into the middle of e multi-byte encoded code point you'll get a task fail.

Comment: @sellibitze -- Figured since the 2 chars are known beforehand, it was alright. Also, would you know how to replace a character in a string in constant time and without using additional variables? For example in most languages strings are just char arrays so you can just do str[i] = 'x' or whatever. I couldn't find a way to do that here.