# How do I replace a single character in a string in constant time and using no additional space?

Tags: regex, string, rust

This isn't the exact use case, but it is basically what I am trying to do:

```
let mut username = "John_Smith";
println!("original username: {}",username);
username.set_char_at(4,'.'); // <------------- The part I don't know how to do
println!("new username: {}",username);
```

I can't figure out how to do this in constant time and using no additional space. I know I could use "replace" but replace is O(n). I could make a vector of the characters but that would require additional space.

I think you could create another variable that is a pointer using something like **as_mut_slice**, but this is deemed unsafe. Is there a safe way to replace a character in a string in constant time and space?

Comment: You may find the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877699/invert-string-in-rust enlightening. Most notably, asserting that the entire thing is ASCII is the only way you can reasonably do this.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan -- I couldn't find any answers that don't require looping over the string. A string is just an array at some point. I feel like there should be a constant time answer to this, no?

Comment: The aspect I wished to draw your attention to is the whole encoding side of it. (Also, if you convert a String into ASCII, you’ve got `Vec<Ascii>` and so regular `Vec` methods work.) But seriously, reconsider whether you should be doing this at all; normally the answer is no, for strings should almost always be being treated as opaque data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to handle only ASCII there is separate type for that:

```
use std::ascii::{AsciiCast, OwnedAsciiCast};

fn main() {
    let mut ascii = "ascii string".to_string().into_ascii();
    *ascii.get_mut(6) = 'S'.to_ascii();
    println!("result = {}", ascii);
}
```

There are some missing pieces (like `into_ascii` for `&str`) but it does what you want.
Current implementaion of `to_/into_ascii` fails if input string is invalid `ascii`. There is `to_ascii_opt` (old naming of methods that might fail) but will probably be renamed to `to_ascii` in the future (and failing method removed or renamed).

Comment: Yea this is pretty much what I was looking for. Guess I'm just used to languages that don't support unicode by default or hide the complexity of it. I'm so used to just getting characters by doing my_str[i]. Either way, thanks.

Comment: Rust has changed a lot in 8 years! `ascii` has been moved out of the core language into a seperate crate, which has had API changes: in the current package instead of https://docs.rs/ascii/0.6.0/ascii/trait.AsciiCast.html you need https://docs.rs/ascii/1.1.0/ascii/trait.ToAsciiChar.html

Answer (score 11):

As of Rust 1.27 you can now use [`String::replace_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range):

```
let mut username = String::from("John_Smith");
println!("original username: {}", username);  // John_Smith
username.replace_range(4..5, ".");
println!("new username: {}", username);       // John.Smith
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3ac84e933ec646e8a05e1e98bfe3ed6b&version=stable&mode=debug))

`replace_range` won't work with `&mut str`. If the size of the range and the size of the replacement string aren't the same, it has to be able to resize the underlying `String`, so `&mut String` is required. But in the case you ask about (replacing a single-byte character with another single-byte character) its memory usage and time complexity are both O(1).

There is a similar method on `Vec`, [`Vec::splice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice). The primary difference between them is that `splice` returns an iterator that yields the removed items.

Answer (score 7):

In general ? For any pair of characters ? It's impossible.

---

A [string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29) is *not* an array. It *may* be implemented as an array, in some limited contexts.

Rust supports Unicode, which brings some challenges:

- a Unicode code point might is an integral between 0 and 2<sup>24</sup>
- a grapheme may be composed of multiple Unicode code points

In order to represent this, a Rust string is (for now) a UTF-8 bytes sequence:

- a single Unicode code point might be represented by 1 to 4 bytes
- a grapheme might be represented by 1 or more bytes (no upper limit)

and therefore, the very notion of "replacing character i" brings a few challenges:

- the position of character `i` is between the index `i` and the end of the string, it requires reading the string from the beginning to know exactly where though, which is O(N)
- switching the i-th character in-place for another requires that both characters take up exactly the same amount of bytes

In general ? It's impossible.

In a particular and very specific case where the *byte* index is known and the byte encoding is known coincide length-wise, it is doable by directly modifying the byte sequence return by [`as_mut_bytes`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_mut_bytes) which is duly marked `unsafe` since you may inadvertently corrupt the string (remember, this bytes sequence must be a UTF-8 sequence).

Comment: I can’t imagine anything that would make Rust change from using UTF-8 for strings. It can be safely assumed to be a constant which will be true forever.

Comment: I'm obviously not a language designer, but why wouldn't they implement something like String, UnicodeString, AsciiString, etc. where the size of each character is known and just have an array under everything? Most languages implement string as an array and it seems like rust breaks the principle of least astonishment for no good reason.

Comment: I get unicode chars are of variable size, I just meant unicode strings probably shouldn't be the default, which I guess is just a design decision at that point. Either way, thanks for the info. At least I have my answer.

Comment: An default to what exactly? That would be like going back to 1990

Comment: @user439299 Actually, if you want to iterate over characters and/or graphemes in Java or .NET, you have to jump through hoops, too. See .NET's [StringInfo.GetNextTextElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hcb622(v=vs.110).aspx). So, "most languages implement string as an array" is an implementation detail that is not relevant to correct usage.